# Method that runs in parallel of a KeyListener

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, keylistener

I have a `KeyListener` that listens to the keyboard on a certain window. If I am off the mark, please feel free to correct me, but the adequate method is called at the event that a key is pressed.

Now, in an infinite loop, I have a method that listens on a socket for input:

```
while (true) {
    inputStream.read();
    ...
}
```

Does this mean that if a key is ever pressed, `keyPressed()` will never be called to pick it up? Do I have to start a separate thread for it?

Answer (score 1):

If the infinite loop is in the same thread, the keylistener would not be called, and even if it were called, nothing will happen since the execution will be in the infinite loop until you exit it in any moment.

If you plan to create an infinite loop (first you should make sure this is the approach you are looking for) most probably you will need a separate thread, and a good design of what exact behavior you want

Comment: So, this is a client that runs on separate machine and waits for data from a server, where "runs" means it monitors keyboard events and acts consequently. I have no way to know when data will arrive on the socket's input stream and keyboard events can occur anytime too. Please feel free to advise any better approach should you have such a thing.